# ASP.NET CORE remote validation and when it fires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been able to get Remote validation working with:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    [Remote(action: "VerifyNameUnique", controller: "ListCategories")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

and

```
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public IActionResult VerifyNameUnique(string name)
    {
        return Json(data: true);
    }
```

and

```
        <div class="form-group required">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But, do we have the ability control whether validation is fired on each change in a Textbox or only when the Submit button is clicked?

Comment: jquery validation is 'lazy'. Once its marked as invalid - i.e. you enter an invalid value and tab out, its validated on `.keyup()`. -Refer [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), in particular the section titled _A few things to look out for when playing around with the demo_.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - very good point! After working with my app, I see that now and I can accept that. Plus I can reference this page you provided!